# KnockoutJS + Symfony2 + Twig collection form add and remove items

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, knockout.js

I am trying to implement Knockout into my Symfony2 projects and I've come to a point where I need to integrate a collectiontype into my form. I have followed Symfony2 documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). I have plenty of experience in SF2. However, I am recently starting on Knockout.

What I would like to know is how can I combine the symfony2's twig {% for bform in form.a.bs %} with the data-bind="foreach: b" so that my table displays the current data and also lets me add/remove using KnockoutJS.

I still don't have a working piece of code because I am thinking how can I achieve this but this is an example of the `<tbody>` of the table:

```
<tbody data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.a.bs.vars.prototype)|e }}">
{% for bForm in form.a.bs %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ form_widget(bForm.first) }}</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(bForm.second) }}</td>       
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

In my Knockout I currently have:

```
function viewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.bs = ko.observableArray();
    self.addB = function() {
        // Logic to add a new form row in the table provided in SF2 documentation above
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I don't know how to proceed in order to wrap this together. I am aware that I can use JSON with Knockout but thinking it from a SF2 perspective, when you hit an action lets say createAAction() {} that returns the .html.twig with the form, All I see in the Knockout documentation is how to retrieve JSON from the server but that's not really my case. I would like for when the page loads with the current information, knockout picks it up.

Let me know if this isn't clear enough.

Comment: Where is your data that you would put into knockout, and how do you make changes to that data?

Comment: Mmm that is a good question, but the data would simply be attached to the formView that gets send to the html.twig.. When I render the form the data is in there {{ form_widget(bla bla bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not going to be any straightforward or worthwhile way to make that work with Knockout. The whole premise of Knockout is that all data is in the viewmodel, and the view reflects the viewmodel and accepts input for the viewmodel. Symphony2 puts the data in the view.

You will do better to use jQuery to perform the DOM manipulations you want to do.

You can certainly use Knockout's observables and computeds behind the scenes if that helps you manage your data dependencies, and you could even put some bindings on the page *as long as they are in pieces of the DOM that will not be managed by anything else*. But combining Knockout bindings with another DOM-constructing system will not work.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Wouldnt make much sense to se Knockout if I dont have the data in the viewmodel, would have to do double work to populate knockout and stuff, I am thinking of using a combination of both knockout and jquey, jquery to handle the dom and knockout to handle data bindings and computable stuff, do you think this is a reasonable approach or should I just stick with jQuery? What I am really trying to automate in a more organized way is the way that dependent things in the view(front end) updates. Like for example labels that have the total amount of a  list of items and things l